# Show progress spinner (refresh) on ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using the ActionBar. I'd like to have a refresh progress spinner on the titlebar, if I set it to spinning - otherwise hide it. Is that possible?:

```
// My menu has a refresh item, but it shouldn't be visible on the
// actionbar unless it's spinning.
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
    android:title="@string/refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh" />
</menu>

...

// When I need to show some work being done on my activity,
// can I somehow now make the spinner associated with the
// refresh item become visible on the action bar?
getActionBarHelper().setRefreshActionItemState(true);
```

I don't want it on the ActionBar unless it's "in progress" / spinning.

Thanks

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Apologies for no code tags, posting from phone...

This is from ActionbarSherlock (Google that if you've not come across it, allows actionbar support in pre honeycomb)

In onCreate of main activity

```
// This has to be called before setContentView and you must use the 
// class in android.support.v4.view and NOT android.view

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

To show/hide progress in action bar. Notice with actionbarsherlock you must use boolean.TRUE/FALSE, not just true/false.........

```
if (getSupportLoaderManager().hasRunningLoaders()) {
   setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.TRUE); 
} else {
   setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.FALSE); 
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks I'll dig around in there a bit. The sample provided with the SDK is not as good as I initially thought. They're using Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE which has the effect of showing the user a titlebar before fully drawn as you want, it looks really unprofessional. Sigh.

Comment: @Jake Wharton I am trying to work this out. When `refresh` button is pressed callback `onOptionsItemSelected` is called. Where do we call `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility` as suggested by MartinS.

Comment: If you're using ActionBarSherlock, make sure to use setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(). Otherwise, your progress indicator will spin all the time and you won't know why.

Comment: and `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);` (as least when using `ActionBarCompat`)

Comment: For ActionBarCompat you need also to `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);` or you will get NullPointerException (details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192148/nullpointerexception-with-progressbar-using-actionbarcompat)

Comment: What if I'm currently inside a fragment?

Comment: Based on my debug getSupportLoaderManager().hasRunningLoaders() is always returning false :( Do you know what's the reason?

Answer (score 3):

If you extends from a ActionBarActivity, try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    boolean showUp=true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.TRUE);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(showUp){
                    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.FALSE);
                }else {
                    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.TRUE);
                }
                showUp=!showUp;
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: "Window" belongs to which package?

Comment: Support library v21 does not support this, so be aware. See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443490/appcompat-show-progress-in-action-bar-causes-npe and https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/#comment-1642002459