# Android ActionBarSherlock displays ProgressBarIndeterminate in Fragment (not FragmentActivity)

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-progressbar

How do I display ProgressBarIndeterminate (or use these)

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

in a `Fragment/SherlockFragment` (not SherlockFragmentActivity)?

Answer (score 3):

```
getActivity.setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

and

```
getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `requestWindowFeature` on a `Fragment`. For setting content to a `Fragment` you need to override `onCreateView()` and return the `View` that your `Fragment` should display.

Probably you should read more on [`Fragments`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: Hmm my ActionBar is implemented within the Fragment, is there a way to display the ProgressBarIndeterminate on the ActionBar?

Comment: you'll need to make some changes probably, to call the `Activity` from your `Fragment`. take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058553/show-progress-spinner-refresh-on-actionbar