# NullPointerException with ProgressBar using ActionBarCompat

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

I'm using ActionBarCompat in support-v7-r18.
When trying to show an indeterminate progress, it works on Galaxy S3 Android 4.1.2 but doesn't on Galaxy Ace Android 2.3.3.

I can't figure why.

The code raising the exception :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    final ActionBarActivity activity = this;
    content = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webContent);
    content.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            activity.setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(true);   <=== Line 88
            activity.setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }
    }
```

The exception :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at  android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.updateProgressBars(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:508)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(ActionBarActivity.java:282)
    at MyActivity.onPageStarted(MyActivityActivity.java:88)
    at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:266)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you please select your line 88 in your posted code.

Comment: Oups, sorry it's  "activity.setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(true);"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);`or         `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);` to onCreate() method before calling setContentView().

Comment: More precisely, you need to add both features to show a progress on android 2.3.3

Comment: and `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.TRUE);`

Comment: still crashing for me when i request both progress and inderminate progress using the supportRequestWindowFeature method....

Comment: On more modern devices (4.0.3+) I don't see this crash at all, but on older ones (a 2.2.1 and 2.3.7 device specifically), I always get this crash. I even tried waiting until the [onPostResume()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPostResume()) method of the Activity lifecycle to use `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(boolean)` and it still happens. I have no idea if Honeycomb era devices do / don't see this crash.

Comment: @JulienC even i need to add both features to show progress, but on doing this both progress spinners are visible , i only want to show the spinner, any idea on that ?