# Android activity - get spinner from action bar

Tags: android, android-activity

I have created a new Activity using Android Studio and I checked the option to have a Action Bar Spinner. In my activity code, I can get the action bar using `getActionBar()`, but I can't figure out how to an instance of the Spinner in the action bar, as I need to set the selected item in code.

Can someone tell how to do this ?

**Edit:**

Code is as follows (its all default code generated by Android Studio) - I need to access Spinner in onResume( ), which I will add :

```
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM 
= "selected_navigation_item";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar to show a dropdown list.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    // Set up the dropdown list navigation in the action bar.
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(
            // Specify a SpinnerAdapter to populate the dropdown list.
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    actionBar.getThemedContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    android.R.id.text1,
                    new String[] {
                            "Email Fragment",
                            "Browser Fragment",
                            }),
            this);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Restore the previously serialized current dropdown position.
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Serialize the current dropdown position.
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM,
            getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the example here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown

If not, please post your code.

**Edit:**
Ok, so with your edit, the issue is that you're creating the ArrayAdapter for the Spinner but not keeping the object anywhere.

You could have a `private ArrayAdapter mArrayAdapter` for your class, then in your onCreate, change to this:

```
// Set up the dropdown list navigation in the action bar.
mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                actionBar.getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[] {
                        "Email Fragment",
                        "Browser Fragment",
                        });

actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(
        // Specify a SpinnerAdapter to populate the dropdown list.
        mArrayAdapter, this);
```

Then you can access mArrayAdapter from your onResume and do what you need there. Haven't tested this code, so YMMV, but if it doesn't work it'd help to see how it fails.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to programatically change the list of items in the Spinner from onResume (that's what I assumed above), or are you trying to change which item is selected? If the latter, then you can use `actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position)` in onResume.

Comment: Ok, it's a better way to do what he wanted, but what if I need to access the spinner instance to do something like, spinner.performClick()?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to call this before set content view (like any other window features):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

and then you can set it true or false

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean);
```

**EDIT:**
Seems like this could be a duplicate. [Show progress spinner (refresh) on ActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058553/show-progress-spinner-refresh-on-actionbar)