# appcompat show progress in action bar causes NPE

Tags: android

After updating my SDK to all the latest Android 5.0 goodies I can't use progress bars built into the ActionBar in appcompat. I have done all the usual fixed (move supportRequestWindowFeature() call to before setContent() and before super call in oncreate) but nothing works. Here is what I'm doing:

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    ...
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                ...
                setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }
    });
```

}
and the stack trace:

```
10-18 19:38:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(11206): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke     virtual method 'void android.support.v7.internal.widget.ProgressBarCompat.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
10-18 19:38:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(11206):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.updateProgressBars(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:786)
10-18 19:38:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(11206):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:692)
10-18 19:38:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(11206):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(ActionBarActivity.java:327)
10-18 19:38:21.053: E/AndroidRuntime(11206):    at com.myapppackage.LoginActivity$2.onClick(LoginActivity.java:82)
```

This is on a Nexus 5 running Android 4.4.4. The app theme inherits from Theme.AppCompat. The app is built with Android 5.0 and targetSDK is 21. When I use setSupportProgress for a normal horizontal progress bar the same thing happens. Any help much appreciated.

EDIT:
Found the problem. In android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper:

```
@Override
public void initIndeterminateProgress() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Progress display unsupported");
}
```

Maybe not a bug but a feature? Toolbars seem to be the new ActionBars.

I have a copy of V20 appcompat on another computer so I'm going back to that.

Comment: Confirmation from Chris Banes https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/#comment-1642002459

Comment: Hey Mark, I had the same problem. I believe the whole point now is that you have to make your own progress bar inside the toolbar. Pretty much what Chris Banes said. I'm looking for solutions that people have done so I don't venture off to make up my own thing.

Answer (score 12):

A possible workaround for this would be to manually add a ProgressBar as a custom view and override **setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility**

In onCreate:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(progressBar);
```

In your activity:

```
@Override
public void setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(boolean visible) {
    getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

Of course switching to a Toolbar and adding the ProgressBar there should be more future-proof.

Comment: This works if you use setCustomView with layout params set to gravity top and width to match parent. Unfortunately, it doesn't cover 100% width of the action bar if there's a title and 3 dot menu present.  I was hoping for the circular style one in the top right of the action bar but this might be a more up-to-date look anyway.

Comment: two progress bar appear dont know why ??

Answer (score 4):

It looks like indeterminate progress and horizontal progress bar are not supported in support library V21. From the android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper:

```
@Override
public void initIndeterminateProgress() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Progress display unsupported");
}
```

Chris Banes has confirmed this: http://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/#comment-1642002459. I am using an old copy of appcompat v20. Here is a zip for anyone who needs it:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2dSjU9N8KdZUEFuMkhLZzJZOFU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** The below is does not work because `ProgressBarCompat` is a hidden class and cannot be added to your XML layout. It feels like a bug in the appcompat library.

---

It is looking for a progress bar in `ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java`:

```
private ProgressBarCompat getCircularProgressBar() {
    ProgressBarCompat pb = (ProgressBarCompat) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.progress_circular);
    if (pb != null) {
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    return pb;
}
```

And using it in the `updateProgressBars()` method in the same class. Looks like it is up to the developer to add a `ProgressBarCompat` to your activity.

Comment: I linked it in my answer but Google is removing this feature from appcompat library. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78310

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else doing an upgrade of their app/libraries - they have dropped support for the progressbar in appsupport v7 library.  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78310