# How can I show a progress bar when a button is clicked?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-progressbar

Please can someone help me put a progress bar, something which looks similar to this; [Example of Progress Bar](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-GxM_gpbWJmE/Tic9OoG7sKI/AAAAAAAACFA/6UnKQ-jEdk8/s1600/ProgressDialog_04.png).

THis is my code ;

```
public class exampleAlert extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View theDIalog = inf.inflate(R.layout.example_xml, null);
    builder.setView(theDIalog);
    builder.setCancelable(true);

    final AlertDialog dialogscreen = builder.create();

    theDIalog.findViewById(R.id.Ok).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setTitle("Loading...");
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait.");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();

            long delayInMillis = 2500;
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }, delayInMillis);



        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder1.setMessage("Write your message here.");
        builder1.setCancelable(true);
        builder1.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //put your code that needed to be executed when okay is clicked
        dialogscreen.dismiss();


        }
        });

        AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
        alert11.show();

        }

        });

        return dialogscreen;

}



 }
```

As you can see I am bringing in an alert dialog when the Ok button is clicked. I would like to bring the progress bar before this dialog comes on the screen.

So please can someone help me do this.

If you need any further detail please comment on this post

Comment: look at this answer [Actionbar loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058553/show-progress-spinner-refresh-on-actionbar)

Comment: I have managed to get somesort of progress bar, I have changed my post. Please can everyone have a look at it. HOwever I want that progressbar to come before the dialog screen but when I run my program the dialog screen comes up with the message and the okay button within the dialog screen after ciicking on the okay button this progress bar comes up on